# Beamer \pause in LaTeX minted

Tags: beamer, minted

How can I `\pause` in the middle of a minted source code in Beamer?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{minted}

...

\newminted{csharp}{bgcolor=gray!25,fontsize=\footnotesize,mathescape}

...

\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{csharpcode}
    public class Objet
    {
        public int Attr1 { get; set; };

        % I want to \pause here

        public int Attr2 { get; set; };
    }
    \end{csharpcode}
\end{frame}
```

I want to show the audience just a part of the code in a first frame and the following in a second frame.

It's useful because if I show everything they will not be able to focus on what I am talking about in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible; why not breaking the code into two parts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use two environments:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{csharp}{bgcolor=gray!25,fontsize=\footnotesize,mathescape}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{csharpcode}
    public class Objet
    {
        public int Attr1 { get; set; };

\end{csharpcode}
\pause\vspace{-2pt}
\begin{csharpcode}

        public int Attr2 { get; set; };
    }
\end{csharpcode}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Put the code in an external file and use inputminted with different start and end lines. Use the standard frame selection tokens for beamer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you were to mock up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that might be even more helpful to the OP!