# \pause of beamer inside a minted environment

Tags: beamer, minted, pause

How can I use \pause command in beamer to pause displaying my code now putted in a minted environment? I have searched on TSE and I found two solutions for quite similar problems but not exactly mine, so I still decided to ask again.

In the [first solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144251/beamer-pause-in-latex-minted), the answer suggested to use to environments, which doesn't help in my case.

In the [second solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26917/beamer-vs-minted-overlays), the answer suggested to use the option `[escapeinside=||]` which seemed useful with white minted default environment, however, mine is not default and for the default white environment I can use multi environment and usual `pause` to get the same effects.

```
\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{lua}
|\pause|print("foo")
|\pause|print("bar")
|\pause|print("baz")
\end{minted}
```

And also, `[escapeinside=||]` doesn't work with my custom `mintedbox` environment.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\tcbuselibrary{minted,breakable,xparse,skins}
%\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{>\/>\/> #1}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\definecolor{bg}{gray}{0.98}
%\definecolor{bl}{rgb}{0.1,0.5,1}
\DeclareTCBListing{mintedbox}{O{}m!O{}}{breakable=true, listing engine=minted, listing only, minted language=#2, 
minted style=default, minted options={gobble=0, breaklines=true, breakafter=,, fontsize=\small, numbersep=8pt,
#1},
boxsep=0pt, left skip=0pt, right skip=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, arc=0pt, leftrule=0pt, 
rightrule=0pt, bottomrule=0pt, toprule=0pt, enhanced}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{Foo}

\begin{minted}[escapeinside=||]{lua}
|\pause|print("foo")
|\pause|print("bar")
|\pause|print("baz")
\end{minted}

Here is mintedbox environment

\begin{mintedbox}[escapeinside=||]{lua}
|\pause|print("foo")
|\pause|print("bar")
|\pause|print("baz")
\end{mintedbox}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I do want to custom something like

```
begin{custompy}
command 1 \pausecommand 
command 2 \pausecommand
\end{custompy}
```

which has the same effect as the normal `\pause` command in `beamer` and doesn't affect this `\pause` in the whole frame or document.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of worrying about the `tcblisting`, you could add a background colour to the minted code:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newminted{lua}{escapeinside=||,bgcolor=gray!15}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\frametitle{Foo}

\begin{luacode}
|\pause|print("foo")
|\pause|print("bar")
|\pause|print("baz")
\end{luacode}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Instead of uncovering the lines, you could completely exclude them from the previous overlays:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\newcounter{foo}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\slideinframe}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile,t]
\frametitle{Foo}

This is some text \pause test \pause

\setcounter{foo}{\slideinframe}
\addtocounter{foo}{1}
\addtocounter{foo}{-\thebeamerpauses}
\begin{minted}[lastline=\thefoo,bgcolor=gray!15]{lua}
print("foo")
print("bar")
print("baz")
\end{minted}
\pause[5]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But the problem is the gray box appears before the 1st line of code appears. I want them to appear simultaneously, or the gray box of 1st line of code appears, then the gray box of 2nd line of code...

Comment: @trequartista Then pause is completely the wrong approach. With pause the future content is just invisible, but will still occupy space.

Comment: @trequartista I added a second solution without pauses

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work if I include some text like: 
`\frametitle{Foo}
This is some text \pause`
inside the frame.

Comment: You can offset the counter the by number of pauses before.

Comment: By offset, do you mean I count the number of pauses before then add them to 3?

Comment: @trequartista No, count the pauses and subtract them from the `foo` counter. Or if you promise to only use pauses before and no other type of overlays, use `beamerpauses` to get the current number + 1: `\setcounter{foo}{\slideinframe}
\addtocounter{foo}{1}
\addtocounter{foo}{-\thebeamerpauses}`

Comment: Thank you. I supposed to write the text before and after the block of codes with many pauses. So I do want to find a global solution.